# Is it safe to share synchronization primitives between processes via shared memory?

Tags: linux

In particular pthread's mutex, condition variable, semaphore, etc.  Can they be shared through a shared memory segment and be guaranteed to function as expected?  My thought is yes since there's no real difference between processes and threads in Linux, but I want to be sure.

Comment: as I know `no real difference between processes and threads in Linux` it is wrong, because every process has their own address space, but threads work in the same address space in their own process. So shared memory it is not achievable through processes there is concept https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication but I'm not sure mutexes or others whether can work or not.

Comment: Processes and Threads in Linux are both just tasks in the kernel.  The only difference is the memory shared between them by default (processes share nothing usually), threads share everything (with a few exceptions).  You can absolutely map a shared memory segment between processes.

Comment: Of course you can map shared memory between processes; that's it's whole reason for existence!

Comment: @Rob: of course you can, but that's not even close to the question I asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be yes.  POSIX doesn't require it to be safe to use mutexes through shared memory, but it works on Linux.  To be safe, one has to set the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute through the [pthread_mutexattr_setpshared](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared) function when creating a lock or condition variable.  This explicitly indicates you want any thread to be able to work on the lock, even through shared memory.

Comment: Functions such as `sem_init()` take a parameter `pshared` to indicate whether the object will be accessed by threads of a single process or by multiple processes.