# Condition Variable in Shared Memory to Wake up Sleeping Process

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory, condition-variable

Suppose we have a data structure in shared memory e.g.

data.h:

```
struct data_in_shm{
  int stuff = 0;
  std::mutex mutex;
  std::condition_variable cv;
};
```

and we have two processes P1 and P2;

P1.cpp:

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <data.h>  //structure for shared memory
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;
bool thread_dead = true;
void inthand(int signum)
{
  stop = 1;
}

void wake_thread(struct data_in_shm* shared_struct)
{
  printf("Waker thread launched \n");
  thread_dead = false;
  while (!stop)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    {
      std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lk(shared_struct->mutex);
      printf("Shared Memory Variable is: %i\n", shared_struct->stuff);
      shared_struct->cv.notify_one();
    }
  }
  thread_dead = true;
  printf("Waker thread destroyed \n");
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("Starting P1, attaching to shm and starting wake thread\n");
  signal(SIGINT, inthand);
  int key = 65;
  int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct data_in_shm), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  if (shmid == -1)
  {
    printf("SHMID generation failed, exiting with error code: %i\n", errno);
    return errno;
  }
  struct data_in_shm* shared_struct = (struct data_in_shm*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
  if (shared_struct == (void*)-1)
  {
    printf("SHMAT generation failed, exiting with error code: %i\n", errno);
    return errno;
  }
  printf("Shared memory attached, launching waker thread\n");
  std::thread{ &wake_thread, shared_struct }.detach();  
  while (!stop || !thread_dead)
  {
  };
  printf("Exiting, and destroying shared memory\n");
  if (shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1)
  {
    printf("Marking shared memory for destruction failed: error %i\n", errno);
  }
  if (shmdt(shared_struct) == -1)
  {
    printf("Detaching from shared memory failed: error%i\n", errno);
  }
}
```

And then we have P2;

P2.cpp:

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <data.h>  //structure for shared memory
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

volatile sig_atomic_t stop;
bool thread_dead = true;

void inthand(int signum)
{
  stop = 1;
}

void increment_thread(struct data_in_shm* shared_struct)
{
  printf("Incrementing Thread Started");
    thread_dead = false;

  while (!stop)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(shared_struct->mutex);
    shared_struct->cv.wait(lk);
    shared_struct->stuff++;
    lk.unlock();
    printf("Incremented Variable, sleeping now.\n");
  }
    thread_dead = true;

}

int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGINT, inthand);
  printf("Starting P2 Incremented thread and attaching to shared memory\n");
  int key = 65;
  int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct data_in_shm), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  if (shmid == -1)
  {
    printf("SHMID generation failed, exiting with error code: %i\n", errno);
    return errno;
  }
  struct data_in_shm* shared_struct = (struct data_in_shm*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
  if (shared_struct == (void*)-1)
  {
    printf("SHMAT generation failed, exiting with error code: %i\n", errno);
    return errno;
  }
  printf("Shared memory attached\n");
  std::thread{ &increment_thread, shared_struct }.detach(); 
  while (!stop || !thread_dead)
  {
  };

  if (shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1)
  {
    printf("Marking shared memory for destruction failed: error %i\n", errno);
  }
  if (shmdt(shared_struct) == -1)
  {
    printf("Detaching from shared memory failed: error%i\n", errno);
  }
}
```

Ideally, each time the waker thread executes its loop, the value of the shared memory variable (stuff) should increment by 1, since the waker thread in P1 should wake up the incrementer thread of P2.

Instead, the P1 waker thread consistently prints that the shared memory variable is zero, and the P2 incrementer thread permanently sleeps.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is how to compile it:

```
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++17 -Iinclude src/P1.cpp -o P1 -pthread
    g++ -Wall -g -std=c++17 -Iinclude src/P2.cpp -o P2 -pthread
    chmod +x P1
    chmod +x P2
```

This is what happens when I launch Process 1:
[image]

and this is what happens when I launch Process 2:
[image]

I am expecting logging messages from P2 when the incrementer thread wakes, as well as the variable in shared memory to increment by 1 with each iteration.

Here is a link to the git repository with the code structured so if you want to test for yourself, you don't need to copy files. https://github.com/Denri006/IPC_CV_SHM

Comment: There is no requirement that `std::condition_variable` work across processes. Consider switching to something that does support cross process use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223266/is-it-safe-to-share-synchronization-primitives-between-processes-via-shared-memo

Comment: Look at `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()` and `pthread_condattr_setpshared()`. Yep, you’ll have to (ideally) create C++ RAII style wrappers around POSIX mutexes and condition variables to make it all work correctly in shared memory.